# change path of saving data of jspdf file

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, doc

I have simple code to save pdf data with jspdf use.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

this code works fine on [offical jspdf](https://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/examples/basic.html)  and save pdf file in downloads. How should I change this code to save in other path?

Comment: Do you mean doc.save('c:/Test.pdf');?

Comment: It does not work

Comment: It save also in downloads, not in the specific path. The name of file changes from test.pdf to c_test.pdf

Comment: Oh, I see you're working in the browser. The browser controls where files are downloaded, not javascript. You would need to change your browser configuration.